# How to restore console alerts in uglifyJsPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs

Do anybody know how to turn back on console log and alerts in Adminator (webpack based, link below). Have tried to turn off each plugin one by one, both production and development mode, unsuccessfully.

I assume that `uglifyJsPlugin` is responsible, but even changing `compress` parameters to false didn't work.

https://github.com/puikinsh/Adminator-admin-dashboard

in `webpack.config.js`

```
// ---------------------------
// @Merging Production Plugins
// ---------------------------

if (manifest.IS_PRODUCTION) {
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        comparisons   : true,
        conditionals  : true,
        dead_code     : false,
        drop_debugger : false,
        evaluate      : true,
        if_return     : true,
        join_vars     : true,
        screw_ie8     : true,
        sequences     : true,
        unused        : true,
        warnings      : false,
      },

      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please disable **drop_console** attribute to **false** and check with below config.

Reference : [compress-options](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony#compress-options)

```
// ---------------------------
// @Merging Production Plugins
// ---------------------------

if (manifest.IS_PRODUCTION) {
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        comparisons   : true,
        conditionals  : true,
        dead_code     : false,
        drop_debugger : false,
        evaluate      : true,
        if_return     : true,
        join_vars     : true,
        screw_ie8     : true,
        sequences     : true,
        unused        : true,
        warnings      : false,
        drop_console  : false
      },

      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
    })
  );
}
```